# Validating XML attribute with values enumeration including ""

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I'm trying to validate an incoming XML. The XML has an attribute ***verb=""***. The XSD has an enumeration of the possible ***verb*** values and it doesn't include the ***""*** option:

```
<xsd:attribute name="verb" use="required">
    <xsd:simpleType>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:NMTOKEN">
            <xsd:enumeration value="Create" />
            <xsd:enumeration value="Delete" />
            <xsd:enumeration value="Retrieve" />
            <xsd:enumeration value="RetrieveByContent" />
            <xsd:enumeration value="Update" />
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:attribute>
```

I tried to add ***`<xsd:enumeration value="" />`*** but it didn't work. Can anyone help me with fixing the XSD?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `xsd:string` (or `xsd:token` whichever makes more sense) as the base instead of `xsd:NMTOKEN`. `xsd:NMTOKEN`, `xsd:NMTOKENS` etc are provided for compatibility with DTD.